# Recognition accuracy decreases as the number of LDA features increase?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, hidden-markov-model

Helloy guys. I'm currently using KALDI building an HMM-GMM system and I added LDA transform to the original 12-dim features, wondering if I can get a better performance of the system.

The input dim is 12 and the number of classes is 25 (5 phones with 3 states each and 2 silence phones with 5 states each => 3*5+2*5=25). So the number of LDA features should vary between 1-12. (If I didn't misunderstand anything.) The training data and testing data are two separated groups but with the same classes.

The singular values calculated by LDA are [ 115.129 6.90348 2.96379 1.33682 0.409236 0.134506 0.105854 0.0630365 0.0466823 0.0144119 0.00462614 0.00395389 ]

The recognition result from the HMM-GMM system was something like this:

1dimLDA feature 6%

2dimLDA feature 3%

3dimLDA feature 4%

4dimLDA feature 5%

5dimLDA feature 9%

and keep increasing (or stay similar) while the non-LDA feature (12dim) got a result of 6%. (So the best result is obtained when only 2 LDA features are used)

Can I ask if this is something normal as the number of LDA features increases, the system performance decreases? Is it like overfitting or just because the third and so on features got "rubbish" information causing lower performance?

Can someone provide kind of advice? Thank you for your help.